# Schema validation failed with the following errors: Data path "" must NOT have additional properties(buildOptimizer)

Tags: angular, angular-universal

When i typing ng add @nguniversal/express-engine and after

npm run dev:ssr

Show this error Schema validation failed with the following errors:
Data path "" must NOT have additional properties(buildOptimizer).

Schema validation failed with the following errors:
Data path "" must NOT have additional properties(buildOptimizer).